# Asset Field: Select a folder instead of all images

Tags: assets, image, assets-field

Is there a way to pick a folder from an asset field?

The goal is to render a dynamic gallery from an asset folder (which is on S3) instead of selecting all images inside a folder by hand.

Use case:
In an asset field, I select folder 'XYZ' and render a gallery from all images which are inside. If a user uploads a new image to the folder 'XYZ', the gallery will be updated automatically.

Problem: 
Currently, I can only handpick the images from a folder. If someone uploads a new image, he/she also has to pick the new image in the asset field. So it is not dynamic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can create a custom field for that purpose, would that be an option for you?

Comment: @RobinSchambach I am not sure. What field type would you use for that?

Comment: A custom field https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/v3/en/field-types.md. You want to create a select for your folder models and return all files that are in the folder with the selected id. It's basically really easy to extend Craft fields for that purpose

Comment: @RobinSchambach ok thanks. I will give it a try. I am very new to PHP so let's see how this goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new field with these functions. Note: this is a very basic example, you would usually want to do this with a template but I don't have much time

```
class FolderAssetField extends Field {
    // Static Methods
    // =========================================================================

    public $folderId;

    /**
     * Returns the display name of this class.
     *
     * @return string The display name of this class.
     */
    public static function displayName(): string{
        return 'Folder';
    }

    /**
     * @param $value
     * @param ElementInterface|null $element
     * @return string
     */
    public function getInputHtml($value, ElementInterface $element = null): string
    {
        $allFileModels = \craft\records\VolumeFolder::find()->all();
        $string = 'select a folder<br><select name="' . $this->handle .  '">';
        /** @var VolumeFolder $folder */
        foreach ($allFileModels as $folder){
            $selected = ((int)$value === $folder->id)? 'selected="selected' : '';
            $string .= '<option ' . $selected .  ' value="' . $folder->id . '">' . $folder->name .  '</option>';
        }
        $string .= '</select>';

        return $string;
    }

}
```

Your field will then contain the `folderId` of the selected folder. You can then  get all assets for this folder with

```
/** @var AssetQuery $assetQuery */
$assetQuery = \craft\elements\Asset::find();
$assets = $assetQuery->folderId($value)->all();
```

or in Twig

```
{% set assets = craft.assets.folderId(entry.fieldHanlde).all() %}
{% for file in assets %}
    {{ file.title }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

You could also use the `normalizeValue` function to prepare this Query. The [Redactor](https://github.com/craftcms/redactor) plugin has some [good examples here](https://github.com/craftcms/redactor/blob/v1/src/Field.php#L220)